# css resource not loaded using h:outputStylesheet

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to get rid of the 1px solid borders automatically created when using the PrimeFaces `p:panelGrid`, but yet all my attempts to do so fail.

I tried to integrate a `style.css` doing:

```
<h:body>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="css/style.css" />
    </f:facet>
    // more code here
</h:body>
```

But when I check in the resulting HTML given back by the application server (I use Wildfly 8) I am unable to finde an entry like `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />`. And because of this missing CSS-entry I am not able to perform any CSS-changes within my document like killing the borders of `p:panelGrid`.

What must I do to integrate the CSS to get rid of the borders in `p:panelGrid`?

Comment: When I do this it works: `<h:head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /></h:head>` but it doesn't work when I do this `<h:head><h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" /></h:head>`. If I use the `h:outputStylesheet` the HTML produced looks like this `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND" />`.

Comment: What is location of your CSS file in your workspace and why don't you try F12 on your browser and check this unwanted borders

Comment: The location of the CSS file in my workspace is `myproject/src/main/webapp/css/style.css`. I solved the border problem earlier using F12 in Firefox. But the `h:outputStylesheet` problem still remains. Any idea?

Comment: It should be webapp/resources/css/style.css

Comment: Ok, tried both, putting the style.css in `webapp/resources/css/` (which I had to create first, and putting `webapp/resources/css/style.css` into `h:outputStylesheet`. I hope I understood you the way you intended, but it still does not work.

Comment: Use <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.CSS as I am seeing u used lib which is defa something. It should work check with the path

Comment: I changed it to `<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />` now, but within the HTML page it is coded like `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/myproject/javax.faces.resource/css/style.css.xhtml" />` and hence does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" and it will generate following HTML output… <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="/myProject/faces/javax.faces.resource/style.css?ln=css" />

Comment: Nope. `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />` generates `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/myproject/javax.faces.resource/style.css.xhtml" />`

Comment: And hence does not work.

Comment: Ok don't use output style inside facet remove it and use after body anyhow u will get the css

Comment: For detail help use below link http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-cascading-style-sheets-css-in-jsf/

Comment: Yeah, tried it, but still doesn't work. I now have `<h:body><h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" /></h:body>` and the resulting HTML is `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/myproject/javax.faces.resource/style.css.xhtml" />`. I already tried to follow mkyoung.com's tutorial, but it doesn't seem to work for me.